# In R, how can I loop over repeated XML nodes, and save text values in a list?

Tags: xml, r

I'm working with XML files from clinicaltrials.gov, which have a structure like this:

```
<clinical_study>
  ...
  <brief_title>
  ...
  <location>
    <facility>
      <name>
      <address>
        <city>
        <state>
        <zip>
        <country>
    </facility>
  </location>
  <location>
    ...
  </location>
  ...
</clinical_study>
```

I'm gathering information from multiple XML files, so the number of locations in each file is unknown and could even be zero.  I need to extract all the information about each location and save into an SQL table. I've had some success using functions from the XML package to extract information from single nodes, e.g.

```
library(XML)
nct_url <- "http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00112281?resultsxml=true"
xml_doc <- xmlParse(nct_url, useInternalNode=TRUE)
title_path <- "/clinical_study/brief_title" 
title_text <- xpathSApply(xml_doc, title_path, xmlValue)
```

I'm experimenting with getNodeSet, and this gives me a set of the right length:

```
doc <- xmlParse("NCT00007501.xml")
locations <- getNodeSet(doc, "/clinical_study/location")
length(locations)
[1] 22
> class(locations)
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

but my attempts to extract information from this set have been mostly fruitless.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example

```
 ns <- getNodeSet(xml, '//clinical_results/outcome_list/outcome/analysis_list/analysis/method')
 element_cnt <-length(ns))
 strings<-paste(sapply(ns, function(x) { xmlValue(x) }),collapse="|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why do you not use again `xpathSApply`, to retrieve locations as you already did for titles?!

```
xpathSApply(xml_doc, "//clinical_study/location" , xmlValue)
```

Comment: The <location> node contains sub-nodes, and xmlValue just removes the tags and concatenates all the values together w/o a separator. If all I wanted was the <location><title></title></location> node, your suggestion is good and would return a list of all the location titles.  Leaving off the "xmlValue" from the end of your suggestion gives me a list of XML fragments, but XML functions like xmlParse expect a file.  Not sure how to process an XML fragment.

Comment: I might have answered my own question ... with your help.  If I save the set of XML fragments in a list, then it seems I can again use `xpathSApply` with "list[1]" where I have "xml_doc" above.  Thanks.

Comment: use dput(object) to see the structure of the object. Also, note that you can prepare the XML file with 2 methods xmlParse and xmlTreeParse. They produce different output. And yet internal nodes yes/no. It is hard to desipher all that. I wish the XML package had more for-dummies vignettes and 3+ examples for each problem.

Comment: The argument above should be `"//clinical_study/location"`. (Double forward slash)

Answer (score 1):

This code will put a subset of nodes that correspond to `<location>` from a clinical trial into a data frame:

```
library(XML)
clinicalTrialUrl <- "http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT01480479?resultsxml=true"
xmlDoc <- xmlParse(clinicalTrialUrl, useInternalNode=TRUE)
locations <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(xmlDoc,"//location"))
```

In this case there are 221 locations. However, the code assumes sort of a flat structure and lumps subnodes together. For example, anything under `<facility>` gets concatenated into a single string. I can go into the subnodes and put them one by one into a dataframe.

Comment: There is a problem with the above solution, in which sub-nodes get concatenated into single long strings. I asked the question in another thread, and it got answered. One effective solution is to flatten the structure of the XML to properly fit tables. Here is the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625960/how-to-convert-an-portion-of-an-xml-into-a-data-frame-properly