# R: XML: Trouble Looping Over NodeSet

Tags: xml, r

I am retrieving information from the [following file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnp2vm5nallfv9d/0103010_honbun_jpcrp030000-asr-001_E00012-000_2015-03-31_01_2015-06-24_ixbrl.htm?dl=0), using the **XML** package in R. I retrieve a set of table nodes, and then want to further use **xpathApply** on each node

```
doc = htmlParse(file.link)
tableNodes = getNodeSet(doc, "//table")

for(i in 1:length(tableNodes)){
    print(xpathApply(tableNodes[[i]],"//tr[1]/td[1]",xmlValue))
}
```

This should return the top-left element from each table in the file, but for some reason each iteration returns the top-left element of the first table. That is, for every i, I get;

```
"事業所名(所在地)"
```

Instead, it should return;

```
i=1: "事業所名(所在地)"
i=2: "会社名事業所名(主な所在地)"
i=3: "会社名(所在地)"
...
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622648/in-r-how-can-i-loop-over-repeated-xml-nodes-and-save-text-values-in-a-list), I also tried using **sapply**, but get similar results - only the entry from the first table is returned.

```
sapply(tableNodes, function(x) { xpathApply(x,"//tr[1]/td[1]",xmlValue) })
```

When I print each Node to the console, different tables are returned, but any ideas why I observe this behaviour? What additional steps do I need to make to return the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the leading `//` in your query, which means anywhere in the XML document starting at the root.  See [xpath expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-path-expressions).

Here is an example.

```
library(XML)

xml <- htmlParse("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp")

tableNodes <- getNodeSet(xml,"//table")

sapply(
  1:length(tableNodes)
  ,function(i) {
    getNodeSet(tableNodes[[i]],"tr[1]/td[1]")
  }
)
```

Comment: One other way to resolve this, suggested by the author of the package was to use the syntax for the context node; `.//tr[1]/td[1]`.